# getting always the default link with ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I need to change the above link from
Voucher to special action..
The new link is getting from 'Slink ' in the DB
So how can I change it so the page will be the link provided in 'Slink' and not the default link

```
   $.ajax({
        url: '/Newsletter/GetUserOrder?id=' + id,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: id,
        success: function (response)
        {
            if (response === "")
            {

                location.href = '/Newsletter/CardDetails'+ id;

            }
            else
            {

                var Bname='';
                var itemsQuantity;
                var name = '';
                var Link="פירוט הטבה"
                $.each(response, function (indexInArray, valueOfElement)
                {

                    Bname += '<div class="card col-md-5">' + '<b>' + valueOfElement.shortNameVar + '</b>' + '<br/> ' + valueOfElement.BusnessName + '</div>' + '<br/>' + '<div class="chip">' + "כמות" + valueOfElement.MemberOrderQuntity + '</div>' +
                        '<b>' + '<div class="flx-aut text-center">' + '<a href="http://www.nofshonit.co.il/Voucher/%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%93-%D7%93%D7%99%D7%92%D7%99%D7%98%D7%9C">' + Link + '</a>' +   '<div>';

                });
```

Comment: Is that really a hardcoded voucher number in the markup there? Anyway, what controller? What method? Is the return type the same?

Comment: @JamesS I meant to voucher in the default `'<a href="http://www.nofshonit.co.il/Voucher/%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%93-%D7%93%D7%99%D7%92%D7%99%D7%98%D7%9C">'`

Comment: So I need it to provide the same link but instead of http://www.nofshonit.co.il/Voucher/%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%93-%D7%93%D7%99%D7%92%D7%99%D7%98%D7%9C will be http://www.nofshonit.co.il/special/%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%93-%D7%93%D7%99%D7%92%D7%99%D7%98%D7%9C

Comment: IS there a controller called 'special'? Does the, im assuming the constructor, take that string as a parameter?